# Odoo (on Debian) - longpolling port is never used/opened

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, long-polling, odoo, odoo-8

There seems to be a problem with Debian distributions (tested for both Wheezy and Squeeze) using Odoo for longpolling port. longpolling port is never used. It supposed to be used wen `workers` parameter is set to be greater than `0`, but it is not used anyway. But testing same thing on Ubuntu, longpolling port is used normally.

There is an original Question (last comment of the issue) https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3793

checking nginx log I see this (everytime it tries to access longpolling through reverse proxy):

```
2015/05/08 07:54:09 [error] 32494#0: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: IP address, server: _, request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8072/longpolling/poll", host: "db.host.eu", referrer: "http://db.host.eu/web"
```

And when I try to connect to `8072` port via telnet:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8072
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

But trying for example:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8069
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
```

So it seems that 8072 port is not used?
In my odoo config it is set to be like this:

```
longpolling_port = 8072
xmlrpc_port = 8069
workers = 2
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
netrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was quite simple, but yet disguised. It was missing python package `psycogreen`. But it was not mentioned as dependency and when installing `im_chat` it didn't require such package. So if you were running Odoo with `--workers=0`, then installed `im_chat` and later switched to for example `--workers=2`, Odoo would not throw any error and longpolling port would never be opened.

Installing this solved it:

```
pip install psycogreen==1.0
```

Comment: What about here? I already had that thing installed but longpolling not working :(

Comment: same as @user568021

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu 16.04, `sudo apt install python-psycogreen` will do it. Rather strange though, that pkg in official repository is not listing it as dependency...

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Xenial and tried with pip install and apt install. Neither worked. The weird thing is that the listener DOES start on the longpolling_port (8072) however Odoo (10) still spits out the `bus.Bus unavailable` error.

Comment: You have to do a reverse proxy for longpolling port if you are enanling workers. Here is a good guide. It is made for odoo 8, but works for newer versions too http://www.schenkels.nl/2014/12/reverse-proxy-with-odoo-8-nginx-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you fixed it already, but seeing i have been looking for an answer and found a fix i'll post it.
This made my Odoo 10 Enterprise installation work again:

1. Install the Python dependencies with the following command:
   sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-docutils python-feedparser python-jinja2 python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-mock python-openid python-psycopg2 python-psutil python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-unittest2 python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi poppler-utils python-pip python-pypdf python-passlib python-decorator gcc python-dev mc bzr python-setuptools python-markupsafe python-reportlab-accel python-zsi python-yaml python-argparse python-openssl python-egenix-mxdatetime python-usb python-serial lptools make python-pydot python-psutil python-paramiko poppler-utils python-pdftools antiword python-requests python-xlsxwriter python-suds python-psycogreen python-ofxparse python-gevent .

(Credits: https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/ ).

2. Make sure in your config you have workers = x 
   X should be a number > 0
3. If you are running behind a reverse proxy (apache / nginx), make sure your config file has the following line:
   proxy_mode = True

Hope this helps others who are having a similar issue